# Use Atom's Hydrogen package with Conda environments in WSL

Tags: atom-editor, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hydrogen

I was trying to setup WSL for Deep Learning/Machine Learning. I have installed Conda environment via WSL. Now I am wondering is there any way to setup atom's hydrogen package to detect conda environments with ipykernels, which are in WSL?

**System:**

- Windows 10
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Miniconda for python 3.7(installed in /home/)

**Already Tried:**

- using `python -m ipykernel install --user --name envName`

Thanks

Comment: What errors did you see?

Comment: `No kernel found`

Comment: Its true. WSL has no kernel.

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue. Have you found any solution? What did you do in the end?

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by setting up a [Hydrogen Remote Host](https://nteract.gitbooks.io/hydrogen/docs/Usage/RemoteKernelConnection.html).

- You need to add the following to the getaways list in Hydrogen's settings:

```
[{
  "name": "WSL",
  "options": {
    "baseUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8888",
    "token": "your_secret_token"
  }
}]
```

- Then set up a public jupyter server with an empty password as explained in the [instructions](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html).
- In WSL run: `jupyter notebook --generate-config` and modify the file `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` changing the line `c.NotebookApp.token = 'your_secret_token'`
- Always in WSL run `jupyter lab` open it in your browser at `localhost:8888` and set an empty password (everybody in your network, and also people outside of it in case you are not behind a firewall, will be able to execute code on your machine if they access to the jupyter server, so be aware of this)
- Start a notebook with the desired kernel.
- Open `Atom > Packages > Hydrogen > Connect to Remote Host`
- You should now be able to select WSL and then as a session, the notebook you started earlier.

Sometimes nothing happens when you click on 'Connect to Remote Host', in that case just retry, eventually it should show up.